# Can you optimize a view with many UNION ALLs to external databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Given these views in a Sql Server 2012 database:

```
create view vManyUnions as
    select 1 as p, a from vSubQuery_1
    union all
    select 2 as p, a from vSubQuery_2
    union all
    select 3 as p, a from vSubQuery_3
    ...
    union all
    select n as p, a from vSubQuery_n

create view vSubQuery_1 as
    select a from [externalDb].[dbo].[someTable] where b = something

create view vSubQuery_2 as
    select a from [externalDb].[dbo].[someTable] where b = somethingElse

create view vSubQuery_3 as
    select a from [externalDb].[dbo].[someTable] where b = somethingElseStill

...

create view vSubQuery_n as
    select a from [externalDb].[dbo].[someTable] where b = youGetTheIdea
```

And given this query:

```
select * from vManyUnions where p = 1
```

What optimizations, if any, can be made such that Sql Server 2012 only evaluates vSubQuery_1 when running the query?

*Note again, the sub query views call external databases.

FOLLOW UP: This was an example I contrived from a proprietary, much more complicated case (~1K subviews) where the execution planner includes more subqueries than the one subquery I expect. Thanks to those that replied and comfirmed that Sql should optimize queries against this type of view. It made me realize I was being lazy and hadn't actually tested my basic assumptions on how the optimizer works.

So I did that. I built a simple proof of concept and confirmed very fast that Sql optimizes the query. Following that, I worked more with the real-world view that still doesn't optimize. I found that, strangely, the planner *is* optimizing out many of the subviews. There are particular subviews that the planner always includes though. At this point I don't know why the planner always includes these particular subviews, any ideas? ...otherwise I'll post something if we figure it out.

Comment: Please add the query plan you get to your question. The setup you have posted here will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `select * from vManyUnions where p = 1` will already avoid having to access the other tables, because of the contradiction optimisation.

If you look at the actual execution plan, you should see that only one of the external tables is actually accessed. Any others would have the NumberOfExecutions property set to zero.

You can see me demonstrate this in a talk that was recorded in 2009 for SQLBits, at http://bit.ly/Simplification

Comment: Thanks Rob, you're correct of course. I posted an edit on my original question. And I watched your talk, very helpful :)

Comment: Where's your original question?

Comment: Oh - you mean this question... right. You should check to see whether some of the things you think aren't needed are actually running at all.

Comment: Yeah, there's two things: a) the runtime of a query against the view is much longer than running the desired subquery by itself ...something like < 0s vs 20s

b) The execution plan shows a > 0 cost % on index seeks (or scans in some cases) for the 'bad' subviews.

Comment: The cost is based on an estimate, even if it didn't actually run those operators. You should always check the NumberOfExecutions. But also, have a look at what is being pulled out of each Scan/Seek, and follow it through to see how it's being used.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for that. I didn't check them all, but spotting a few I see they all show NumberOfExecs is 1. Seeing how things are being used is confusing me so far ...I'll look more, but upstream from each scan\seek are all the things I would see *as if* the subview was the one being selected. But the actual row results all look OK. I'm misunderstanding something somewhere :)